# Using Ormlite to Group query conditions

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I'm trying to generate the SQL query which looks something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Contact Where UserId = @UserId AND (FirstName = 'John' OR Surname = 'Smith')
```

This is what I can do:

```
Db.From<Contact>().Where(c => c.UserId == userId)
.And("(FirstName = {0} OR Surname = {1})"), firstName, surname);
```

Considering also that the Surname condition is optional, which means with a raw string we can build the string. Is there a way to not have to use a raw sql string?

Possible solution:

```
var q = Db.From<Contact>().Where(c => c.UserId == userId);
if (onlyFirstName) {
    q.And(c => c.FirstName == firstName);
} else if (onlySurname) {
    q.And(c => c.Surname == surname);
} else {
    q.And(c => c.FirstName == firstName || c.Surname = surname);
}
```

Does anyone know of a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ev = Db.From<Contact>().Where(c => c.UserId == userId);
if (someCase)
    ev.And(c => c.FirstName == firstName || c.Surname == surname);
```

or if no someCase

```
var ev = Db.From<Contact>().Where(c => c.UserId == userId && (c.FirstName == firstName || c.Surname == surname));
```

Comment: Ah yep (except your OR should be ||). I forgot to mention that I need to make second condition in the grouped AND to be optional. So I don't want to filter by Surname in some cases. And I guess I simplified my example because my actual query requires the use of a full text search.

Comment: Sorry fixed it. Is it better now?

Comment: Better, but missing some cases, which I've included in the OP now. Just waiting to see if anyone else has a better solution.

Comment: Added another expression case without someCase variable